# Java regex - condition between two full regex

Tags: java, regex

I like to create in Java a regular expression (regex) which should be true if other than one or more zero comes or other than `3037` comes.

I have prepared 2 different regex for this 2 conditions

- For `0` condition: `[^0]+`
- For `3037` condition: `^((?!^3037$).)*$`

but do not know how to put an `OR` between them.

**Pass case:**

```
001
002
30377
23037
2
4
55
```

**Fail condition:**

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
3037
```

Comment: Can you add some valid and invalid examples in your question.

Comment: I am simply looking for regex for condition NOT 0 (or more 0 )  OR NOT 3037.

Comment: I have one configuration table where I have to put error response in form of regex of java .. so if other than 0 or 3037 comes then it should be error ..

Comment: You may use: `^(?!3037$)[^0]*$`

Comment: thanks for reply but it is not working here 3037 is whole string this condition is giving no match found on 003 and 23037 but it should give match found as it is under condition

Comment: I have already asked you to **post valid and invalid examples** in your question that you haven't done so far as that's the reason people are voting to close this question.

Comment: btw you wrote that validation should fail if there is any zero in input so in that case `23037` or `003` will fail because both contain zero.

Comment: Sorry for less clarity .. Pass case : 001 , 002 ,30377 ,23037 , 2 ,4 ,55 ,..... Fail condition : 0 , 00 ,000 ,0000 , 00000,  3027 so only in this condition fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this combination regex for 2 conditions (and it doesn't use alternation):

```
^(?!(?:3037|0+)$)\d*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG7YUz/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start of input
- `(?!(?:3037|0+)$)`: Negative lookahead to assert input is not `3037` and not all zeroes
- `\d*`: Match any digit 0 or more times
- `$`: End of input

Comment: thanks for reply but it is not working here 3037 is whole string this condition is giving no match found on 003 and 23037 but it should give match found as it is under condition

Comment: my current condition is [^0]+ :Anything other than zero is bad, but want to add 3037 with it that is Anything other than zero or 3037 should be  bad,

Comment: Sorry for less clarity .. Pass case : 001 , 002 ,30377 ,23037 , 2 ,4 ,55 ,..... Fail condition : 0 , 00 ,000 ,0000 , 00000, 3027 so only in this condition fail.

Comment: Its very urgent sir , could you please help

Comment: typo mistake it is 3037  .. sorry again ..

Comment: Thanks Sir , it is working fine ..